# Release Management does not work with Windows 8.1 Credentials

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have a Release Management Update 4 Server, running under a domain account. I can connect to it from domain laptop, but when I tried to do the same from a non-domain workstation, despite having added my domain credential to Windows Credentials as per [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/12/configuring-release-management-to-work-across-untrusted.aspx), the client app claims that the current user does not have access to Release Management. From the same workstation I can log into the web interface for RM. I also tried [this approach](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.com/2014/07/connecting-release-management-clients.html).

Any pointers how could I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the second link provided correct answer:

> The first option is to use the domain account of the user and add that to Release Management together with the local username:
>
> Add the domain account for the user to Release Management as both a Release Manager and a Service User.
>   Add the username that the user is using on his local pc to Release Management as a Service User (and as a Release Manager if the user should be a Release Manager).
>
> So for example, my local pc is running under an account named Wouter and my domain account is WdK1111. This means that I need to add both WdK1111 and Wouter to Release Management. Make sure to add Wouter without any machine name in front of it. Just add it as a plain username. You also don’t have to create a local shadow account named Wouter.

It only worked **after** I have changed my domain account to be Service User and Release Manager.

I have also disabled going through proxy servers in my proxy config file. Just in case.